# Swift URLSession completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am trying to make an **API call in my Swift** project. I just started implementing it and i am trying to return a **Swift Dictionary** from the call.

But I think i am doing something wrong with the completion handler!
I am not able to get the returning values out of my API call.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SafariServices
import Foundation

var backendURLs = [String : String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {



    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
    var webView: WKWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.getBackendURLs { json in
            backendURLs = self.extractJSON(JSON: json)
            print(backendURLs)


        }
        print(backendURLs)

    }


    func getBackendURLs(completion: @escaping (NSArray) -> ()) {

        let backend = URL(string: "http://example.com")

        var json: NSArray!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: backend! as URL) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            do {

                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
                completion(json)

            } catch {

                #if DEBUG

                    print("Backend API call failed")

                #endif
            }


        }

        task.resume()


    }


    func extractJSON(JSON : NSArray) -> [String : String] {

        var URLs = [String : String]()

        for i in (0...JSON.count-1) {

            if let item = JSON[i] as? [String: String] {
                URLs[item["Name"]! ] = item["URL"]!

            }
        }

        return URLs
    }
}
```

The first print() statements gives me the correct value, but the second is "nil".

Does anyone have a suggestion on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Declare your dictionary like this, var backendURLs: [String : String] = [:]

Comment: Call is asynchronous, need to wait response to get results. For this one of your print method returns nil.

Comment: @lubilis: thanks for the answer. i know it is asynchronous, but i thought the completionHandler would handle that

Comment: You say "The first print() statements gives me the correct value, but the second is "nil".", do you mean in `viewDidLoad()`? and is the first one the one inside your callback and the second one the one outside of the callback?

Comment: @pbodsk yes, first one inside the callback, second one outside.

Comment: I think print method inside completionHandler give the right result. Other print method returns nil obviously and i don't understand why this is considered as an issue. Am i right?

Comment: That's right, completionHandler _does_ handle this, but only _inside_ the closure. So whatever you need to do with the results, you start from inside the block.

Comment: @lubilis because I need the results outside of the completionHandler

Comment: You need results outside of the completionHandler ok, but you must start from there and write code there or call another method; otherwise you can't have api results. You need to have downloaded json to make logic on it

Comment: sorry @lubilis, I just thought I'd write something a bit more detailed and I couldn't fit it inside a comment

Comment: i tried something like this: DispatchQueue.main.async {
                backendURLs = URLs
            } but it does not work! Can not find any example on how to update the data

Answer (score 1):

Technically @lubilis has answered but I couldn't fit this inside a comment so please bear with me.

Here's your `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.getBackendURLs { json in
       backendURLs = self.extractJSON(JSON: json)
       print(backendURLs)
   }
   print(backendURLs)
}
```

What will happen is the following:

1. `viewDidLoad` is called, `backendURLs` is nil
2. you call `getBackendURLs`, which starts on another thread in the background somewhere.
3. *immediately* after that your code continues to the outer `print(backendURLs)`, which prints nil as `backendURLs` is still nil because your callback has not been called yet as `getBackendURLs` is still working on another thread.
4. At some later point your `getBackendURLs` finishes retrieving data and parsing and executes this line `completion(json)`
5. *now* your callback is executed with the array and your inner `print(backendURLs)` is called...and `backendURLs` now has a value.

To solve your problem you need to refresh your data inside your callback method.

If it is a `UITableView` you could do a `reloadData()` call, or maybe write a method that handles updating the UI for you. The important part is that you update the UI *inside* your callback, because you don't have valid values until then.

#### Update

In your comments to this answer you say:

> i need to access the variable backendURLs right after the completionHandler

To do that you could make a new method:

```
func performWhateverYouNeedToDoAfterCallbackHasCompleted() {
    //Now you know that backendURLs has been updated and can work with them
    print(backendURLs)
    //do what you must
}
```

In the callback you then send to your `self.getBackendURLs`, you invoke that method, and if you want to be sure that it happens on the main thread you do as you have figured out already:

```
self.getBackendURLs { json in
   backendURLs = self.extractJSON(JSON: json)
   print(backendURLs)
   DispatchQueue.main.async { 
       self.performWhateverYouNeedToDoAfterCallbackHasCompleted()
   } 
}
```

Now your method is called *after* the callback has completed.

As your `getBackendURLs` is an asynchronous method you can not know when it has completed and therefore you cannot expect values you get from `getBackedURLs` to be ready straight after calling `getBackendURLs`, they are not ready until `getBackendURLs` has actually finished and is ready to call its callback method.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! But i am not sure how to update the data in the dictionary.

Comment: Is there a reason you have declared `backendURLs` _outside_ your `ViewController`?

Comment: Isn't your `backendURLs` updated when you do this? `backendURLs = self.extractJSON(JSON: json)
            print(backendURLs)`. I mean, don't you see the correct values printed there?

Comment: i need to access the variable backendURLs right after the completionHandler (where my second print statement is placed). Some time after that i need it in another class. I tried updating the dictionary through **DispatchQueue.main.async {
                backendURLs = URLs
                
            }** but that did not work. I see the correct values in the completionHandler. But i am not able to update the dictionary outside of it